# How do I configure a naked domain name to work using Heroku's SSL endpoint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku, dns

I recently added SSL functionality to my Rails app running on Heroku. I successfully purchased and created a certificate for my domain and using a CNAME in GoDaddy, the WWW subdomain of my app works correctly when a user browses to www.myappname.com

The page loads without any warnings and the certificate works as is supposed to.

The CNAME looks something like this:
**host:** www
**points to:** myappnamefoobar-1234.herokussl.com

However when I simply go to the "naked" domain name - myappname.com, a certificate error comes up.

How do I configure the DNS settings in GoDaddy to make this work?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords

There is a whole article in Heroku's docs about naked domains but I don't see how this would apply to GoDaddy's DNS manager.

I know that Heroku has some sort of IP based SSL that is paid but is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use rack-rewrite:

https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite

It allows Rails to do a redirect from mydomainname.com to www.mydomainname.com since Heroku doesn't allow naked domains.

You then use your DNS manager to point www.mydomain.com to Heroku's SSL endpoint (paid, $20 per month).

Comment: Do you have an example of how this helps?  Aren't you still going to get a certificate error when pointing to mydomainname.com?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe GoDaddy supports such functionality.

The best option is to use something like DNSimple's [ALIAS record type](http://blog.dnsimple.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-alias-that-works/) which provides root-domain support to a CNAME record.

You could then setup your records like so (assuming the use of the [SSL Endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint) for SSL).

```
| type  | name | target                  |
| ALIAS |      | tokyo-123.herokussl.com |
| CNAME | www  | tokyo-123.herokussl.com |
```

Though there are other DNS providers that provide similar ALIAS record functionality, it is not something in the DNS spec. This is why we have yet to provide thorough documentation on using such records. However, we aim to rectify this in the near future given the lack of clear guidance for those wanting root domain support.

Keep an eye out on [using AWS Route 53 as your Heroku app's DNS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53) as well. I believe it is, or soon will be possible, to accomplish this on R53 soon.

Answer (score 0):

If the certificate you purchased has a Common Name `"www.yourdomain.com"` and you browse to the site using any other URL you will receive a certificate warning in you browser.

The warning is telling you that the URL does not match the domain name.

One way to get around this issue is to purchase a wildcard certificate. This allows `*.yourdomain.com"`.

Comment: But the wildcard cert won't match a naked domain.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with that same issue over and over. I always had to set up a 301 SSL redirection by myself all the time, so at some point I got tired and decided to create https://www.nakedssl.com to solve that exact problem. It's free for one domain :).

Disclaimer: Obviously, I'm part of the team that created NakedSSL and some people may consider this self-promotion – even if we offer the service for free. In any case, I think it's still a good workaround until all DNS Management providers support CNAME/ALIAS on naked domains.